# Prevent remove blocks from template

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

First of all i'm using acf to create gutenberg blocks (i think it's important to say about it).

I made custom post type for my restaurant menu, where i want to force exactly the same layout for each
posts.
I made background block  to can adding blocks inside there.

```
<div class="background">
    <div class="background-color" style="background-color: <?php echo $background ?>"></div>
    <InnerBlocks />
</div>
```

To get similar layout to each posts i set template parametr in my cpt

```
'template_lock' => 'all',
'template' => [
    ['acf/background', ['className' => 'meal_description', 'data' => ['admin_section_name' => 'Meal description']], [
                ['core/paragraph', ['align' => 'center', 'placeholder' => __('Your block there', 'restaurant')]],
            ]],
        ];
```

Unfortunately  when i set template_lock to all i cant add block in my 'inner_blocks" called background.
I'm looking for solution in which admin could add some block only in predefined blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding `templateLock="false"` to the `InnerBlocks` element?

E.g. `<InnerBlocks templateLock="false"/>`

`templateLock` is passed down to child elements, so setting the value on the `InnerBlocks` should overwrite the parent value.

https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/master/packages/block-editor/src/components/inner-blocks#templatelock

> If locking is not set in an InnerBlocks area: the locking of the
> parent InnerBlocks area is used.

Comment: Thank, work perfect ;)
I didn't think that would be easy like that.